# Couldn't sign you in; This browser or app may not be secure, Try using different browser

Tags: java, selenium

I have to login to gmail account using selenium script, but I am getting
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypq56.png)

as read from other sources google doesn't allow to use automation script to login

Machine: MacOS
Programming language: Java

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Selenium and Selenium Driver available to you?

Comment: Yes @JonasTuemandMøller but it seems we cannot automate gmail

Answer (score 0):

For this the only work around is that we load our profile data in chrome at the time of launch, so it will have all the data of our profile, passwords, login details, so on the time of launch you will be logged in your gmail account

How to do it:

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/Users/<your user 
            name>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome");
        

        options.addArguments("--disable-blink- 
            features=AutomationControlled");
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[] 
            {"enable-automation", "enable-logging", "disable- 
            notifications"});
        
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).